# prove or disprove Composition of linear transformations is one-one

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ and $F$ be 2 linear transformations from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n $.Then prove or disprove

$T \circ F=0 \to T$  is one-one.

> $|TF|$$=0$ $\implies$ $|T|$$|F|$$=0$ $\implies$ either $|T|$=$0$ or $|F|$=$0$
>
> $\implies$ either $T$ is not one-one or $F$ is not one-one.
>
> So $T$ need not be one-one.
>
> Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Do you mean that for *any* $T$ and $F$...

Comment: yes.The Qn is like this...

Comment: $T\circ F$ is one-to-one $\Leftrightarrow$ both $T$ and $F$ are one-to-one

Comment: @Tani Can you give me an example where $T\circ F$ is one-to-one but $T$ is not?

Comment: @ Gregory Grant: Could U plz check the Qn now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to give a counterexample. Let $T(x) = 0$ and $F(x) = 0$. Then $T \circ F(x) = T(F(x)) = T(0) = 0$ which is not one-to-one unless $n = 0$.

In fact, you *have* to give a counterexample.

Comment: Ok..Thank you... But do u know my method of solving the problem is true or not?

Comment: @Tani No. The only way of solving it is giving a counterexample.